# array element cannot be bridged to Objective-C after migration to Swift 1.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, swift

Yesterday I have switched my IOS Swift project to the new XCode 6.3 and Swift 1.2. I have so far got everything to build nicely, but at one point the app crashes with the error message "fatal error: array element cannot be bridged to Objective-C" at a line that looks like this:

```
let services = services as! [ServiceObject]
```

I have read that the error is because I have Objective C objects as members in the Swift Array which is now not automatically bridged to NSArray anymore, so I would have to either make my objects of type ServiceObject non-Obj-C or declare "services" as an NSArray. The strange thing is that ServiceObject is not an Objective-C object. This is the declaration of the class:

```
class ServiceObject: MonitoringObject {
    let serviceDescription: String
    let host: HostObject

    var duration = 0
    var plugin_output = ""
    var active_checks_enabled = 0
    var display_name = ""
    var has_been_checked = 0
    var acknowledged = 0
    var acknowledgement_type = 0
    var scheduled_downtime_depth = 0
    var is_flapping = 0
    var state = ServiceState.OK


    var name: String {
        return serviceDescription
    }


    init(serviceDescription: String, host: HostObject) {
        self.host = host
        self.serviceDescription = serviceDescription
    }

    var durationText: String {
        if duration == -1 || duration == 0{
            return "N/A"
        } else if duration > 86400 {
            let days = Int(floor(Float(duration) / 86400))
            let hours = Int(floor(Float(duration % 86400) / 3600))
            return "\(days)d, \(hours)h"
        } else if duration > 3600 {
            let hours = Int(floor(Float(duration) / 3600))
            let minutes = Int(floor(Float(duration) % 3600 / 60))
            return "\(hours)h, \(minutes)m"
        } else if duration > 60 {
            let minutes = Int(floor(Float(duration) / 60))
            let seconds = duration % 60
            return "\(minutes)m, \(seconds)s"
        } else {
            return "\(duration)s"
            }
    }
}
```

Also, the protocol "MonitoringObject" which ServiceObject conforms to is not Obj-C:

```
protocol MonitoringObject {
    var name: String { get }
}
```

Does anybody have any clue where the error and the crash come from?

Edit: this is the whole method where the line that fails is contained, to make the context more clear:

```
private func buildHostServicesIndex(services: [MonitoringObject]) -> [HostServicesEntry] {
    //typealias HostServicesEntry = (HostObject, [ServiceObject])
    let services = services as! [ServiceObject]
    let hosts = services.map {
        (service) -> HostObject in
        service.host
    }
    let distinctHosts = Helpers.distinct(hosts)

    return distinctHosts.map {
        (host) -> HostServicesEntry in
        return (host, services.filter {
            (service) -> Bool in
            service.host == host
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Please tag the correct languages next time, you tagged C and C++ when the question relates to Objective-C

Comment: Of what type is `services` declared before you try to cast it to `[ServiceObject]`?

Comment: If it's an `NSArray` before the error message makes sense because `NSArray` cannot contain non-objc objects.

Comment: I was not aware having tagged my question with C and C++. If I did, I am sorry.

Comment: the array "services" is declared as [MonitoringObject], an array of objects that comply to the MonitoringObject protocol which is the one that also ServiceObject complies to.

Comment: I just put all your code into a playground and it has no errors. Have you tried cleaning the build folder, restarting Xcode, and rebuilding the project?

Comment: This is strange. I can confirm it does not throw an error in playground, and it also compiles fine in the project, but it crashes at the moment of using it. Cleaning the build folder has not helped.

Comment: Additional information: the MonitoringObject protocol has actually been prefixed with @objc before, but that was changed during the migration to Swift 1.2. May it be it is still cached somewhere?